# Trying to add social media links to Drupal website

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to add social media icons to my drupal website and followed [this guide](https://opensenselabs.com/blog/tech/add-social-media-icon-drupal-8) to try and install them. The module seems to install fine, however when I try to configure it to add different links on clicking save it brings me to a webpage that simply says `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling the plugin and that didn't seem to do anything. Are there some permissions I'm missing in my set up? I'm pretty much brand new to drupal

Edit: The url of the error is `admin/structure/block/manage/socialmedialinks?destination=/node`
and some of the error log:

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator::isValid() must implement interface Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\EmailValidation, bool given,
```

Comment: What is the URL of the page that shows the error? Enable better error reporting to get a better understanding of what the error may be, take a look at [THIS](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127182/how-do-i-enable-developer-debug-mode) to see how it's done

Comment: @2pha I didn't realize there was a whole Drupal stack exchange, nice. After some more experimentation it looks like it's only an issue with specifying an email address (instagram was added fine.) I added some error message information to my post.

Comment: There is an issue for the module (with a patch) that seems to relate to your problem [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_media_links/issues/3054183). hmm, maybe this should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the social_media_links drupal module version 8.x-2.6 has a bug when it checks the validity of email addresses.
There is an issue in the module's issue queue for it [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_media_links/issues/3054183).
There is a patch attached to the issue (attached below):

```
diff --git a/src/Plugin/SocialMediaLinks/Platform/Email.php b/src/Plugin/SocialMediaLinks/Platform/Email.php
index 007e59f..2926d47 100755
--- a/src/Plugin/SocialMediaLinks/Platform/Email.php
+++ b/src/Plugin/SocialMediaLinks/Platform/Email.php
@@ -4,7 +4,6 @@ namespace Drupal\social_media_links\Plugin\SocialMediaLinks\Platform;

 use Drupal\social_media_links\PlatformBase;
 use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
-use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator;
 use Drupal\Core\Url;

 /**
@@ -29,9 +28,9 @@ class Email extends PlatformBase {
    */
   public static function validateValue(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $form) {
     if (!empty($element['#value'])) {
-      $validator = new EmailValidator();
+      $validator = \Drupal::service('email.validator');

-      if (!$validator->isValid($element['#value'], TRUE)) {
+      if (!$validator->isValid($element['#value'])) {
         $form_state->setError($element, t('The entered email address is not valid.'));
       }
     }
```

Comment: That's definitely the problem I'm having, thank you. Updating the code, is there anything I will need to for the plugin to pick up the change, or just try and add an email address again?